# Android : To shift the common code of all activities to a base class.. the application crashes

Tags: android, inheritance, base-class

I have the following BaseClass:

```
public class BaseClass extends Activity implements MusicUtils.Defs,
    View.OnTouchListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
private static final int USE_AS_RINGTONE = CHILD_MENU_BASE;

private boolean mOneShot = false;
private boolean mSeeking = false;
private boolean mDeviceHasDpad;
private long mStartSeekenter code herePos = 0;
private long mLastSeekEventTime;
private IMediaPlaybackService mService = null;
private RepeatingImageButton mPrevButton;
private ImageButton mPauseButton;
private RepeatingImageButton mNextButton;
private Worker mAlbumArtWorker;
private AlbumArtHandler mAlbumArtHandler;
private Toast mToast;
private int mTouchSlop;
private ServiceToken mToken;

public BaseClass() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    mAlbumArtWorker = new Worker("album art worker");
    mAlbumArtHandler = new AlbumArtHandler(mAlbumArtWorker.getLooper());

    mCurrentTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currenttime);
    mTotalTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totaltime);

    mPrevButton = (RepeatingImageButton) findViewById(R.id.prev);
    mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(mPrevListener);
    mPrevButton.setRepeatListener(mRewListener, 260);
    mPauseButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pause);
    mPauseButton.requestFocus();
    mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(mPauseListener);
    mNextButton = (RepeatingImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(mNextListener);
    mNextButton.setRepeatListener(mFfwdListener, 260);
    seekmethod = 1;

    mDeviceHasDpad = (getResources().getConfiguration().navigation ==

    Configuration.NAVIGATION_DPAD);

    if (icicle != null) {
        mOneShot = icicle.getBoolean("oneshot");
    } else {
        mOneShot = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("oneshot", false);
    }

    mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(BaseClass.this).getScaledTouchSlop();
  }



  Handler mLabelScroller = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) msg.obj;
        int x = tv.getScrollX();
        x = x * 3 / 4;
        tv.scrollTo(x, 0);
        if (x == 0) {
            tv.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
        } else {
            Message newmsg = obtainMessage(0, tv);
            mLabelScroller.sendMessageDelayed(newmsg, 15);
        }
    }
   };


    Cursor c = MusicUtils.query(this, ContentUris.withAppendedId(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, audioid),
            new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC }, null, 

     null,
            null);
    boolean ismusic = true;
    if (c != null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            ismusic = c.getInt(0) != 0;
        }
        c.close();
    }
    if (!ismusic) {
        return false;
    }

    boolean knownartist = (artist != null)
            && !MediaStore.UNKNOWN_STRING.equals(artist);

    boolean knownalbum = (album != null)
            && !MediaStore.UNKNOWN_STRING.equals(album);

    title = getString(R.string.mediasearch, title);

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.setAction(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_SEARCH);
    i.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query);
    if (knownartist) {
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_ARTIST, artist);
    }
    if (knownalbum) {
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_ALBUM, album);
    }
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_TITLE, song);
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_FOCUS, mime);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, title));
    return true;
}

private OnSeekBarChangeListener mSeekListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
        mLastSeekEventTime = 0;
        mFromTouch = true;
    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int progress,
            boolean fromuser) {
        if (!fromuser || (mService == null))
            return;
        long now = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        if ((now - mLastSeekEventTime) > 250) {
            mLastSeekEventTime = now;
            updateTrackInfo();
            mPosOverride = mDuration * progress / 1000;
            try {
                mService.seek(mPosOverride);
            } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            }

            // trackball event, allow progress updates
            if (!mFromTouch) {
                refreshNow();
                mPosOverride = -1;
            }
        }
    }



private View.OnClickListener mPauseListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doPauseResume();
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener mPrevListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mService == null)
            return;
        try {
            if (mService.position() < 2000) {
                mService.prev();
            } else {
                mService.seek(0);
                mService.play();
            }
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        }
    }
};

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    try {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
            if (!useDpadMusicControl()) {
                break;
            }
            if (mService != null) {
                if (!mSeeking && mStartSeekPos >= 0) {
                    mPauseButton.requestFocus();
                    if (mStartSeekPos < 1000) {
                        mService.prev();
                    } else {
                        mService.seek(0);
                    }
                } else {
                    scanBackward(-1,
                            event.getEventTime() - 

      event.getDownTime());
                    mPauseButton.requestFocus();
                    mStartSeekPos = -1;
                }
            }
            mSeeking = false;
            mPosOverride = -1;
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
            if (!useDpadMusicControl()) {
                break;
            }
            if (mService != null) {
                if (!mSeeking && mStartSeekPos >= 0) {
                    mPauseButton.requestFocus();
                    mService.next();
                } else {
                    scanForward(-1,
                            event.getEventTime() - 

     event.getDownTime());
                    mPauseButton.requestFocus();
                    mStartSeekPos = -1;
                }
            }
            mSeeking = false;
            mPosOverride = -1;
            return true;
        }
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

private boolean useDpadMusicControl() {
    if (mDeviceHasDpad
            && (mPrevButton.isFocused() || mNextButton.isFocused() 

      || mPauseButton
                    .isFocused())) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    int repcnt = event.getRepeatCount();

    if ((seekmethod == 0) ? seekMethod1(keyCode) : seekMethod2(keyCode))
        return true;

    switch (keyCode) {
    /*
     * // image scale case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Q: av.adjustParams(-0.05, 0.0,
     * 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,-1.0); break; case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_E: av.adjustParams(
     * 0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); break; // image translate case
     * KeyEvent.KEYCODE_W: av.adjustParams( 0.0, 0.0,-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
     * break; case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_X: av.adjustParams( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     * 0.0, 0.0); break; case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A: av.adjustParams( 0.0,-1.0,
     * 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); break; case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D: av.adjustParams(
     * 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); break; // camera rotation case
     * KeyEvent.KEYCODE_R: av.adjustParams( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,-1.0);
     * break; case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_U: av.adjustParams( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     * 0.0, 1.0); break; // camera translate case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Y:
     * av.adjustParams( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,-1.0, 0.0); break; case
     * KeyEvent.KEYCODE_N: av.adjustParams( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
     * break; case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_G: av.adjustParams( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,-1.0,
     * 0.0, 0.0); break; case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_J: av.adjustParams( 0.0, 0.0,
     * 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0); break;
     */

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SLASH:
        seekmethod = 1 - seekmethod;
        return true;

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
        if (!useDpadMusicControl()) {
            break;
        }
        if (!mPrevButton.hasFocus()) {
            mPrevButton.requestFocus();
        }
        scanBackward(repcnt, event.getEventTime() - 

      event.getDownTime());
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
        if (!useDpadMusicControl()) {
            break;
        }
        if (!mNextButton.hasFocus()) {
            mNextButton.requestFocus();
        }
        scanForward(repcnt, event.getEventTime() - event.getDownTime());
        return true;

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S:
        toggleShuffle();
        return true;

    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE:
        doPauseResume();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private void scanBackward(int repcnt, long delta) {
    if (mService == null)
        return;
    try {
        if (repcnt == 0) {
            mStartSeekPos = mService.position();
            mLastSeekEventTime = 0;
            mSeeking = false;
        } else {
            mSeeking = true;
            if (delta < 5000) {
                // seek at 10x speed for the first 5 seconds
                delta = delta * 10;
            } else {
                // seek at 40x after that
                delta = 50000 + (delta - 5000) * 40;
            }
            long newpos = mStartSeekPos - delta;
            if (newpos < 0) {
                // move to previous track
                mService.prev();
                long duration = mService.duration();
                mStartSeekPos += duration;
                newpos += duration;
            }
            if (((delta - mLastSeekEventTime) > 250) || repcnt < 0) 

            {
                mService.seek(newpos);
                mLastSeekEventTime = delta;
            }
            if (repcnt >= 0) {
                mPosOverride = newpos;
            } else {
                mPosOverride = -1;
            }
            refreshNow();
        }
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
    }
}

private void scanForward(int repcnt, long delta) {
    if (mService == null)
        return;
    try {
        if (repcnt == 0) {
            mStartSeekPos = mService.position();
            mLastSeekEventTime = 0;
            mSeeking = false;
        } else {
            mSeeking = true;
            if (delta < 5000) {
                // seek at 10x speed for the first 5 seconds
                delta = delta * 10;
            } else {
                // seek at 40x after that
                delta = 50000 + (delta - 5000) * 40;
            }
            long newpos = mStartSeekPos + delta;
            long duration = mService.duration();
            if (newpos >= duration) {
                // move to next track
                mService.next();
                mStartSeekPos -= duration; // is OK to go 


          negative
                newpos -= duration;
            }
            if (((delta - mLastSeekEventTime) > 250) || repcnt < 0) {
                mService.seek(newpos);
                mLastSeekEventTime = delta;
            }
            if (repcnt >= 0) {
                mPosOverride = newpos;
            } else {
                mPosOverride = -1;
            }
            refreshNow();
        }
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
    }
}

private void doPauseResume() {
    try {
        if (mService != null) {
            if (mService.isPlaying()) {
                mService.pause();
            } else {
                mService.play();
            }
            updateTrackInfo();
            refreshNow();
            setPauseButtonImage();
        }
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
    }
}

private void toggleShuffle() {
    if (mService == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        int shuffle = mService.getShuffleMode();
        if (shuffle == MediaPlaybackService.SHUFFLE_NONE) {


    mService.setShuffleMode(MediaPlaybackService.SHUFFLE_NORMAL);
            if (mService.getRepeatMode() ==            

    MediaPlaybackService.REPEAT_CURRENT) {
                mService.setRepeatMode(MediaPlaybackService.REPEAT_ALL);
            }
            showToast(R.string.shuffle_on_notif);
        } else if (shuffle == MediaPlaybackService.SHUFFLE_NORMAL
                || shuffle == MediaPlaybackService.SHUFFLE_AUTO) {
            mService.setShuffleMode(MediaPlaybackService.SHUFFLE_NONE);
            showToast(R.string.shuffle_off_notif);
        } else {
            Log.e("MediaPlaybackActivity", "Invalid shuffle mode: "
                    + shuffle);
        }
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
    }
}

private void cycleRepeat() {
    if (mService == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        int mode = mService.getRepeatMode();
        if (mode == MediaPlaybackService.REPEAT_NONE) {
            mService.setRepeatMode(MediaPlaybackService.REPEAT_ALL);
            showToast(R.string.repeat_all_notif);
        } else if (mode == MediaPlaybackService.REPEAT_ALL) {
            mService.setRepeatMode(MediaPlaybackService.REPEAT_CURRENT);
            if (mService.getShuffleMode() != MediaPlaybackService.SHUFFLE_NONE) {
                mService.setShuffleMode(MediaPlaybackService.SHUFFLE_NONE);
            }
            showToast(R.string.repeat_current_notif);
        } else {
            mService.setRepeatMode(MediaPlaybackService.REPEAT_NONE);
            showToast(R.string.repeat_off_notif);
        }
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
    }

}

private void showToast(int resid) {
    if (mToast == null) {
        mToast = Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
    mToast.setText(resid);
    mToast.show();
}

private void startPlayback() {

    if (mService == null)
        return;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String filename = "";
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri != null && uri.toString().length() > 0) {
        // If this is a file:// URI, just use the path directly instead
        // of going through the open-from-filedescriptor codepath.
        String scheme = uri.getScheme();
        if ("file".equals(scheme)) {
            filename = uri.getPath();
        } else {
            filename = uri.toString();
        }
        try {
            if (!ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT.equals(scheme)
                    || !MediaStore.AUTHORITY.equals(uri.getAuthority())) {
                mOneShot = true;
            }
            mService.stop();
            mService.openFile(filename, mOneShot);
            mService.play();
            setIntent(new Intent());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("MediaPlaybackActivity", "couldn't start playback: " + ex);
        }
    }

    updateTrackInfo();
    long next = refreshNow();
    queueNextRefresh(next);
}

private ServiceConnection osc = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName classname, IBinder obj) {
        mService = IMediaPlaybackService.Stub.asInterface(obj);
        startPlayback();
        try {
            // Assume something is playing when the service says it is,
            // but also if the audio ID is valid but the service is paused.
            if (mService.getAudioId() >= 0 || mService.isPlaying()
                    || mService.getPath() != null) {
                // something is playing now, we're done
                setPauseButtonImage();
                return;
            }
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        }
        // Service is dead or not playing anything. If we got here as part
        // of a "play this file" Intent, exit. Otherwise go to the Music
        // app start screen.
        if (getIntent().getData() == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setClass(BaseClass.this, MusicBrowserActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        finish();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName classname) {
        mService = null;
    }
};

private void setPauseButtonImage() {
    try {
        if (mService != null && mService.isPlaying()) {
            mPauseButton
                    .setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
        } else {
            mPauseButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        }
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
    }
}

private TextView mCurrentTime;
private TextView mTotalTime;

private long mPosOverride = -1;
private boolean mFromTouch = false;
private long mDuration;
private int seekmethod;
private boolean paused;

private static final int REFRESH = 1;
private static final int QUIT = 2;
private static final int GET_ALBUM_ART = 3;
private static final int ALBUM_ART_DECODED = 4;

private void queueNextRefresh(long delay) {
    if (!paused) {
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(REFRESH);
        mHandler.removeMessages(REFRESH);
        mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, delay);
    }
}

private long refreshNow() {
    if (mService == null)
        return 500;
    try {
        long pos = mPosOverride < 0 ? mService.position() : mPosOverride;
        long remaining = 1000 - (pos % 1000);
        if ((pos >= 0) && (mService.duration() > 0)) {
            mCurrentTime.setText(MusicUtils
                    .makeTimeString(this, pos / 1000));

            if (mService.isPlaying()) {
                mCurrentTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                // blink the counter
                int vis = mCurrentTime.getVisibility();
                mCurrentTime
                        .setVisibility(vis == View.INVISIBLE ? View.VISIBLE
                                : View.INVISIBLE);
                remaining = 500;
            }

        } else {
            mCurrentTime.setText("--:--");

        }
        // return the number of milliseconds until the next full second, so
        // the counter can be updated at just the right time
        return remaining;
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
    }
    return 500;
}

private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {

        case REFRESH:
            updateTrackInfo();
            long next = refreshNow();
            queueNextRefresh(next);
            break;

        case QUIT:
            // This can be moved back to onCreate once the bug that prevents
            // Dialogs from being started from onCreate/onResume is fixed.
            new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseClass.this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.service_start_error_title)
                    .setMessage(R.string.service_start_error_msg)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.service_start_error_button,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }).setCancelable(false).show();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};

private BroadcastReceiver mStatusListener = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(MediaPlaybackService.META_CHANGED)) {
            // redraw the artist/title info and
            // set new max for progress bar
            updateTrackInfo();
            setPauseButtonImage();
            queueNextRefresh(1);
        } else if (action.equals(MediaPlaybackService.PLAYBACK_COMPLETE)) {
            if (mOneShot) {
                finish();
            } else {
                setPauseButtonImage();
            }
        } else if (action.equals(MediaPlaybackService.PLAYSTATE_CHANGED)) {
            setPauseButtonImage();
        }
    }
};

private static class AlbumSongIdWrapper {
    public long albumid;
    public long songid;

    AlbumSongIdWrapper(long aid, long sid) {
        albumid = aid;
        songid = sid;
    }
}

private void updateTrackInfo() {
    if (mService == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        String path = mService.getPath();
        if (path == null) {
            finish();
            return;
        }

        long songid = mService.getAudioId();
        if (songid < 0 && path.toLowerCase().startsWith("http://")) {
            // Once we can get album art and meta data from MediaPlayer, we
            // can show that info again when streaming.
            mAlbumArtHandler.removeMessages(GET_ALBUM_ART);
            mAlbumArtHandler.obtainMessage(GET_ALBUM_ART,
                    new AlbumSongIdWrapper(-1, -1)).sendToTarget();
        } else {
            String artistName = mService.getArtistName();
            if (MediaStore.UNKNOWN_STRING.equals(artistName)) {
                artistName = getString(R.string.unknown_artist_name);
            }
            String albumName = mService.getAlbumName();
            long albumid = mService.getAlbumId();
            if (MediaStore.UNKNOWN_STRING.equals(albumName)) {
                albumName = getString(R.string.unknown_album_name);
                albumid = -1;
            }
            mAlbumArtHandler.removeMessages(GET_ALBUM_ART);
            mAlbumArtHandler.obtainMessage(GET_ALBUM_ART,
                    new AlbumSongIdWrapper(albumid, songid)).sendToTarget();
        }
        mDuration = mService.duration();
        mTotalTime.setText(MusicUtils
                .makeTimeString(this, mDuration / 1000));
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        finish();
    }
}

public class AlbumArtHandler extends Handler {
    private long mAlbumId = -1;

    public AlbumArtHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        long albumid = ((AlbumSongIdWrapper) msg.obj).albumid;
        long songid = ((AlbumSongIdWrapper) msg.obj).songid;
        if (msg.what == GET_ALBUM_ART
                && (mAlbumId != albumid || albumid < 0)) {
            // while decoding the new image, show the default album art
            Message numsg = mHandler.obtainMessage(ALBUM_ART_DECODED, null);
            mHandler.removeMessages(ALBUM_ART_DECODED);
            mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(numsg, 300);
            Bitmap bm = MusicUtils.getArtwork(BaseClass.this, songid,
                    albumid);
            if (bm == null) {
                bm = MusicUtils.getArtwork(BaseClass.this, songid, -1);
                albumid = -1;
            }
            if (bm != null) {
                numsg = mHandler.obtainMessage(ALBUM_ART_DECODED, bm);
                mHandler.removeMessages(ALBUM_ART_DECODED);
                mHandler.sendMessage(numsg);
            }
            mAlbumId = albumid;
        }
    }
}

public static class Worker implements Runnable {
    private final Object mLock = new Object();
    private Looper mLooper;

    /**
     * Creates a worker thread with the given name. The thread then runs a
     * {@link android.os.Looper}.
     * 
     * @param name
     *            A name for the new thread
     */
    Worker(String name) {
        Thread t = new Thread(null, this, name);
        t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        t.start();
        synchronized (mLock) {
            while (mLooper == null) {
                try {
                    mLock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Looper getLooper() {
        return mLooper;
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            Looper.prepare();
            mLooper = Looper.myLooper();
            mLock.notifyAll();
        }
        Looper.loop();
    }

    public void quit() {
        mLooper.quit();
    }
}
```

}

And I want to extend this Class.. But the program crashes showing null pointer exception at this base class.. The base class doesn't have any content view and it points to the buttons (ex.previous and next button), and shows null pointer.. please guide me to solve this problem.

Comment: your constructor is not the good one.

Comment: Check what's null (preferably using the logcat) and find out why it is.

Comment: (also, when you have a crash, post the full stacktrace.)

Comment: It shows null pointer exception at:

Comment: mPrevButton = (RepeatingImageButton) findViewById(R.id.prev);
    mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(mPrevListener);

Comment: i haven't set any content view in Base class so it is not getting any refrence.

Comment: You have answered your own question. `i haven't set any content view in Base class so it is not getting any refrence.`

Comment: but if i set the content view in the parent class and also in the child class the program doesn't execute properly..
Can we set contentview in both parent and child class???????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set contentview in the child class and parent class can access it.